# How do I link Methods/Functions in Kotlin?

Tags: function, kotlin, methods

I have tried getting this to work a few different ways but just cant seem to wrap my head around it. In Version 1 it tells me that changeDue is not used, and in Version 2 it just runs blank. I'm using code playground if this changes anything  Any help is appreciated.

Version 1:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
var changeDue = 1.23;
fun truncate(changeDue: Double): Double{
var numberOfQuarters = changeDue /.25;

println(numberOfQuarters);

var remainingChange = changeDue - numberOfQuarters * .25;
println(remainingChange);
return changeDue
}
}
```

Version 2: Tried using a class

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    class quarters{
    var changeDue = 1.23;
    fun truncate(changeDue: Double): Double{
    var numberOfQuarters = changeDue /.25;

    println(numberOfQuarters);

    var remainingChange = changeDue - numberOfQuarters * .25;
    println(remainingChange);
    return changeDue
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It's not common to use nested functions (functions defined within other functions) in Kotlin. It's possible, as this question demonstrates; and there are some cases where it's useful (if you need a helper function that's only used within one other function), but they're relatively rare in practice. So unless there's a good reason here, I'd suggest moving your `truncate()` function outside your `main()` function. (That would make the answer to your question clearer, too!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of remarks to your code:

- Use `val` whenever possible instead of `var`. Having variables that do not change their value after being set the first time will help you avoid common mistakes / bugs in your code.
- In Kotlin there is no need to use `;` at the end of each statement.

Now back to your question. In your code, you were not calling `truncate()` anywhere. Simple declaring the function does not call it. The following works as expected:

```kotlin
import kotlin.math.floor

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    fun truncate(changeDue: Double): Double {
        val numberOfQuarters: Double = floor(changeDue / 0.25)
        println(numberOfQuarters)

        val remainingChange = changeDue - numberOfQuarters * 0.25
        println(remainingChange)

        return changeDue
    }

    println(truncate(1.23))
}
```

However, the output is:

```
4.0
0.22999999999999998
1.23
```

As you can see `0.22999999999999998` is not the exact result you were expecting. So that we avoid this you need to use `BigDecimal` instead of `Double` as follows:

```kotlin
import java.math.BigDecimal
import kotlin.math.floor

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    fun truncate(changeDue: BigDecimal): BigDecimal {
        val numberOfQuarters: BigDecimal = floor(changeDue.toDouble() / 0.25).toBigDecimal()
        println(numberOfQuarters)

        val remainingChange = changeDue - numberOfQuarters * 0.25.toBigDecimal()
        println(remainingChange)

        return changeDue
    }

    println(truncate(1.23.toBigDecimal()))
}
```

Which will return:

```
4.0
0.230
1.23
```

Another possibility would be to use a monetary library as the one discussed in https://www.baeldung.com/java-money-and-currency.

Answer (score 0):

You were never calling relevant class/function

Try this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    fun truncate(changeDue: Double): Double{
        var numberOfQuarters = changeDue /.25;

        println(numberOfQuarters);

        var remainingChange = changeDue - numberOfQuarters.toInt() * .25;
        println(remainingChange);
        return changeDue
    }
    println(truncate(1.23))
}
```

[ref](https://pl.kotl.in/YgP3Buf6n)

Comment: thank you I see where I went wrong, however i was trying to get to round to the lowest whole number for the quarters and the remaining change separate. 4 quarters and 23 remain. i tried to input floor but it threw me codes., how would i input that or is there a better way?

Comment: just convert to `Int` using `.toInt()` it's the easiest way to floor