# Quarter counter (kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, coin-change

Ok, so first off I want to say that I am a newer programmer and I'm self taught. I'm currently trying to wrap my mind around how I would make a program (I'm using Kotlin) that would count the number of quarters out of a give value, and state the left over change.

so if I type input: 1.45

output will tell me:

5 quarters

0.20 Change

Now, I have done research on void methods, but I'm still confused on what that looks like. would anyone be willing to help me out on how id get started with this?

I mean like a quarter in terms of USD. So if you have $1.40 / $0.25 (quarter) = 5 Quarters and $0.20 left over. So I'm trying to make something that counts currency. I already have a weak code that calculates the math, but I need the number of quarters and left over change separated on 2 different lines of output.

Comment: Good question and my apologies for not specifying. I mean like a quarter in terms of USD. So if you have $1.40 / $0.25 (quarter) = 5 Quarters and $0.20 left over. So I'm trying to make something that counts currency. I already have a weak code that calculates the math, but I need the number of quarters and left over change separated on 2 different lines of output.

Comment: Check my answer in a similar question --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/70188551/16572295.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `println` to put each of the outputs on seperate lines

```kotlin
fun main() {
    change(1.25)
    changeWithNames(1.25)
}

fun change(x: Double) {
    println(x.div(0.25).toInt()) // toInt to cut off the remainder
    println(x.rem(0.25).toFloat()) // toFloat so that it rounds to the nearest hundreds place
}

fun changeWithNames(x: Double) {
    println("${"%s".format(x.div(0.25).toInt())} quarters")
    println("${"%.2f".format(x.rem(0.25))} Change")
}

fun changeWithDimes(x: Double) {
    var q = x.div(0.25).toInt() // Quarters
    var d = x.rem(0.25).div(0.10).toInt() // Dimes
    var rem = (x - (q * 0.25 + d * 0.10)).toFloat() // Remainder
    println(q) 
    println(d)
    println(rem)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! now might I pester you for something additional? Say I wanted it to add the number dimes in addition to the quarters, what would that look like? 

For example:
having $1.60, which would be 6 quarters and 1 dime output

Comment: I added the dimes

Comment: would you be willing to explain how you are using the rem() operator? More specifically, why do you have it filled with 0.25?

Comment: The rem() operator gives the remainder after dividing. I have .25 in it because you want to get the remainder after removing the quarters.

Answer (score 2):

```
fun main() {
    val input = "1.45"

    // here you convert the input into minor units, e.g. $1.45 => 145 cents
    val total = (input.toFloat() * 100).toInt()

    // here you get whole number of quarters
    val quartersCount = total / 25

    // here you get the change and convert it back to major units (20 cents => $0.2)
    val change = (total - 25 * quartersCount) / 100f

    println("$quartersCount quarters")
    println("${"%.2f".format(change)} Change")  // bit more complex just to keep 2 decimal places
}
```

Comment: @Alex.T it's just an illustration of algorithm to a "newer programmer". Float money is discouraged from using in commercial software which is obviously not the case here